# aligning 3 divs, 1 div to take the full height and 2 to share height

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make a content row that is made of 4 divs:

1 container div
3 divs inside the container:
1 image - taking the full height
2 text - sharing the height , but taking a seperate line for each of them.

it should look like this:
[image]

I don't know which position/display CSS to use. the options are endless and I can't find a combination that works. Besides the code in the example I've tried other combination of css display properties like block, inline-block and more.

this is the code I've tried:

```css
div.contentItemDiv {
display:inline-flex;
height:80px;
width:100%;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

div.picItemDiv {
display:flex;
height:100%;
width:20%;
border:1px dashed;
}

div.itemTitleDiv {
display:flex;
height:30px;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
width:40%;
}

div.itemInfoDiv {
display:flex;
height:50px;
width:40%;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentItemDiv">
<div class="picItemDiv"><img src="pic.jpg" ></div>
<div class="itemTitleDiv">a title</div>
<div class="itemInfoDiv">some content</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I doubt the options are endless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick code example that looks like your screenshot:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="imageWrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/60" />
  </div>
  <div class="textContent">
    <p>
      This is the title
    </p>
    <span>
      This is the sub-title.
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS to it:

```
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.imageWrapper {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.imageWrapper img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.textContent {
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.textContent p {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here's a fiddle to see the result:
https://jsfiddle.net/40pht3kf/

Comment: thanks! that works :)

is it possible to seperate the title text and content text into two seperate divs?
not crucial for this example, but just so I can learn how to understand aligning with css better.

Comment: You could basically put any HTML you want into the `.textContent` container and the content would align at the right of the image. I've updated the example and added a second one with some div's and extra code to show you some alternatives. I hope this helps you out: https://jsfiddle.net/40pht3kf/1/